# bash script for ping the two ip adresses alternatively in a single script

Tags: bash, cron

how we can run two functions alternatively in a single script we can put in cron tab for every 5 min then  1st time it would be run we have to exicute first function not second function at the next time cron tab running we exicute second function not first function

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's cron based every 5 minutes you can check if the minutes are odd or even and call the appropriate function accordingly like this:

```
if [[ $(( $(date '+%M') % 2 )) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "Even"; else echo "Odd"; fi
```